# Dot Product with a CUDA kernel for big vector sizes returns wrong results

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

I am trying to implement a CUDA Kernel, that is calculating the dot product of two vectors. For small vector sizes the code works properly and I get the correct results, but for bigger ones, it is just calculating them wrong. 
I was implementing three different ways to calculate the dot product:

- **serial** version (straight in c++ without any optimization)
- **CUDA** Kernel
- **CUBLAS** version

My main in the cpp-File looks like following:

```
float *h_x,*h_y;
float res1=0.0, res2=0.0, res3=0.0;

h_x=(float*)malloc(Main::N*sizeof(float)); random_ints_Vec(h_x);
h_y=(float*)malloc(Main::N*sizeof(float)); random_ints_Vec(h_y);

double serialTimer;
double cublasTimer;
double cudaTimer;

res1=serial_dotProd(h_x,h_y,&serialTimer);  
res2=cublas_dotProd(h_x,h_y,&cublasTimer);
res3=cuda_dotProd(h_x,h_y,&cudaTimer);      

free(h_x); free(h_y);
```

**serial** version:

```
float Main::serial_dotProd(float* x, float* y, double* time){
std::clock_t start;
start = std::clock();

float res1=0.0;
for (int i=0;i<Main::N;++i) {
    res1+=x[i]*y[i];
}

*time= ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
return res1;}
```

**CUDA** Version:

```
float Main::cuda_dotProd(float *h_x,float *h_y,double* time){
float *d_x,*d_y,*d_res, *h_res;
h_res=(float*)malloc(Main::BLOCKS_PER_GRID*sizeof(float));

size_t bfree, afree, total;
cudaMemGetInfo(&bfree,&total);

cudaMalloc((void**) &d_x,Main::N*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_y,Main::N*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_res,Main::BLOCKS_PER_GRID*sizeof(float));
cudaCheckErrors("cuda malloc fail");

cudaMemGetInfo(&afree,&total);
std::cout<<" > memory used for cuda-version:"<< (bfree -afree)/1048576<< "MB ("<<total/1048576 <<"MB)" <<"\n";

cudaMemcpy(d_x,h_x,Main::N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_y,h_y,Main::N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   

std::clock_t start;
start = std::clock();   
DotProdWrapper(d_x,d_y,d_res,(Main::N+Main::THREADS_PER_BLOCK-1)/Main::THREADS_PER_BLOCK,Main::THREADS_PER_BLOCK,Main::N);

*time= ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

cudaMemcpy(h_res,d_res,Main::BLOCKS_PER_GRID*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

float c= 0;
for (int i=0;i<Main::BLOCKS_PER_GRID;++i){
  c+=h_res[i];
}
cudaFree(d_x);
cudaFree(d_y);
cudaFree(d_res);    

free(h_res);
return c;}
```

**CUDA** Kernel:

```
__global__ void DotProd(float* x, float* y, float* scalar,unsigned long int N){
    extern __shared__ float cache[];

    int tid = threadIdx.x+ blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int cacheIndex = threadIdx.x;

    float temp=0;
    while (tid<N){
        temp+=x[tid]*y[tid];
        tid +=blockDim.x*gridDim.x; 
    }
    cache[cacheIndex]=temp;
    __syncthreads();

    int i=blockDim.x/2;
    while(i!=0){
        if (cacheIndex<i)
            cache[cacheIndex]+=cache[cacheIndex+i];
        __syncthreads();
        i/=2;
    }
    if(cacheIndex==0)
        scalar[blockIdx.x]=cache[cacheIndex];
}
```

**CUBLAS** version:

```
float Main::cublas_dotProd(float *h_x,float *h_y, double* time){
    float *d_x,*d_y;
    float *res;
    float result=0.0;
    cublasHandle_t h;
    cublasCreate(&h);
    cublasSetPointerMode(h, CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE);

    size_t bfree, afree, total;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&bfree,&total);

    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_x,Main::N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_y,Main::N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc( (void **)(&res), sizeof(float) );
    cudaCheckErrors("cublas malloc fail");

    cudaMemGetInfo(&afree,&total);

     cudaMemcpy(d_x, h_x, Main::N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(d_y, h_y, Main::N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cublasSetVector(Main::N,sizeof(float),h_x,1,d_x,1);
    cublasSetVector(Main::N,sizeof(float),h_y,1,d_y,1);


    std::clock_t start;
    start = std::clock();

    cublasSdot(h,Main::N,d_x,1,d_y,1,res);

    *time= ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cudaMemcpy(&result, res, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_y);
    cudaFree(res);
    return result;
}
```

The **results** that I get after the calculation with the the different settings are listed:

- N=204800 , THREADS_PER_BLOCK:512,  BLOCKS_PER_GRID:400
  serial_dotProd=**4.15369e+06** ; cublas_dotProd=**4.15369e+06** ; cuda_dotProd=**4.15369e+06**
- N=20480000 , THREADS_PER_BLOCK:512,  BLOCKS_PER_GRID:40000
  serial_dotProd=**4.04149e+08** ; cublas_dotProd=**4.14834e+08** ; cuda_dotProd=**4.14833e+08**

I don't know why, but after a certain size of my vectors I just get wrong result. The vectors do fit into the SDRAM and the shared memory for each block has also enough space to allocate the memory.
Thank's a lot in advance.

Comment: How do you know what the correct result is? Try running the serial version with a double precision variable for the running sum for an enlightening experiment. In the meantime I'll look for a link to the CUDA documentation that explains this.

Comment: I thought that the serial version is just straight forward and so assumed that this is the correct result. I tried it with double precision but i still get the same results.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you did something wrong in your `double` test if you got the same results.  [here](http://pastebin.com/Zy2A6scp) is the reason that I say that.  I'm reasonably sure that if you did a proper job of converting your serial version to `double`, you would see that the results line up numerically with the CUDA/CUBLAS `float` results.

Comment: This question is effectively asking "why is this code not working?"  For questions of [that type](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you are supposed to provide a [mcve]  What you've provided so far is not one.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. @RobertCrovella I will keep this in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has come up so often that Nvidia devoted [an entire section of the CUDA Floating Point and IEEE 754](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/#dot-product-accuracy-example) guide to it. It's also briefly mentioned in the [CUDA C Best Practices Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#floating-point-math-is-not-associative).

The short explanation is twofold:

- Unlike the corresponding exact mathematical operations, floating point arithmetic operations are not associative due to the rounding errors involved. This means that reordering the summation from a straight serial sum into a tree structure suitable for parallel execution will change the result slightly (more so with increasing number of values summed over). Coincidentally, the tree arrangement in most cases also gives a result closer to the exact mathematical sum than the sequential sum.
- The CUDA compiler tends to be more aggressive in the use of fused multiply-add  (FMA, a multiply-then-add-operation where the intermediate rounding stage is omitted). Again, the mathematically correct result tends to be closer to the result obtained using FMA.

So the probable answer is that the results obtained with CUDA are likely closer to the exact result than a simple serial CPU version (which is why I asked you to perform the experiment again using increased precision).